# Vuetify Vue - Always listening for sliding events, but only return the value once

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I installed the vuetify plugin for the project in order to use a colorpicker plugin. Due to special requirements, I need to manually change the function and style of the plugin.

[image: Plugin]

The plug-in has a scroll bar, each time you slide the button, it will return a current color hex value.

Now I need to make it slideable, but only return a current color value when I let go.

what should I do?

Here is how to listen to scroll events

```
  if ('touches' in e) {
    this.app.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMouseMove, mouseMoveOptions);//滑动
    Object(_util_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["addOnceEventListener"])(this.app, 'touchend', this.onSliderMouseUp, mouseUpOptions);
  } else {
    this.app.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove, mouseMoveOptions);
    Object(_util_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["addOnceEventListener"])(this.app, 'mouseup', this.onSliderMouseUp, mouseUpOptions);
  }//addEventListener is a custom function,listener event just once.
```

when slider moves

```
 onMouseMove: function onMouseMove(e) {
      var value = this.parseMouseMove(e).value;
      this.internalValue = value;

    },
parseMouseMove: function parseMouseMove(e) {
  var start = this.vertical ? 'top' : 'left';
  var length = this.vertical ? 'height' : 'width';
  var click = this.vertical ? 'clientY' : 'clientX';

  var _a = this.$refs.track.getBoundingClientRect(),
      _b = start,
      trackStart = _a[_b],
      _c = length,
      trackLength = _a[_c];

  var clickOffset = 'touches' in e ? e.touches[0][click] : e[click]; // Can we get rid of any here?
  // It is possible for left to be NaN, force to number

  var clickPos = Math.min(Math.max((clickOffset - trackStart) / trackLength, 0), 1) || 0;
  if (this.vertical) clickPos = 1 - clickPos;
  if (this.$vuetify.rtl) clickPos = 1 - clickPos;
  var isInsideTrack = clickOffset >= trackStart && clickOffset <= trackStart + trackLength;
  var value = parseFloat(this.min) + clickPos * (this.maxValue - this.minValue);
  return {
    value: value,
    isInsideTrack: isInsideTrack
  };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vue.js, I can recommend you to use Vue.js 'Event Handling', instead of `addEventListener`, in you `<template>` part, like:

```
<div
  @mousedown="moveStartMethod($event)"
  @mousemove.prevent="moveMotionMethod"
  @mouseup="moveEndMethod"
>
</div>
```

Then in your `<script>` part, you can call the methods:

```
moveStartMethod: function (event) {
  ...
},
```

more info: https://learnvue.co/2020/01/a-vue-event-handling-cheatsheet-the-essentials/ and search for 'Handling mouse modifiers' part